# Xcode Error "Expression Result Unused"

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting an yellow error in my code and I'm not sure really why I'm getting it. Here is my code:

```
for (int lives = 5; lives > 0; lives--)
{
     self.HangmanStatus.text = @"Lives Left: %d", lives; //<-- Getting error here
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?

Comment: The reason for the confusing error message is that in (Objective) C the comma in your example (`...%d", lives`) is actually a use of the *comma operator* - which is little used - and not a use of the comma as a separator. (@JohnSauer has already pointed you to how to fix your code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
self.HangmanStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Lives Left: %d", lives];
```

Look at [NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 4):

Is this your first time creating an NSString? You're not using [any of the NSString methods used to create one.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-CJBCJHHI)